# Remix solidity compiler is not compiling properly offline, why?

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache

I'm a beginner learn solidity by myself. However, I'm getting remix compiler issues. Solidity compiler do not compile unless I connect to the internet and I sometimes do not get internet. How can I solve this please help. It says "Compiling..." but not unless I connect to the Internet. I've tried to install ganache-cli to deploy my contract in it but still it requires internet.

I've tried to search on internet and youtube videos but I didn't got anything usefull